# How to find element on page using ruby

Tags: ruby, find, element, page-object-gem

I use Ruby's PageObject for testing and have an element

```
button(:showLocs,:title=>"Show All Items")
```

in my page-class.

What method I should use to check that page includes this object?
I think that it should look as

```
if self.showLocs_element.find then #doing smth
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`button` accessor](http://rubydoc.info/github/cheezy/page-object/master/PageObject/Accessors#button-instance_method) creates three methods - one to click a button, another to return the button element, and another to check the button's existence. The example in the documentation being:

```
button(:purchase, :id => 'purchase')
# will generate 'purchase', 'purchase_element', and 'purchase?' methods
```

In your specific case, this means that you can check the existence of the button by using the method:

```
showLocs?
```

So your `if` statement could be:

```
if showLocs?
  #doing smth
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using PageObject with Watir, you would check an objects existence by using the .exists? method on the object in question. In addition, there are also .visible? (returns true if the object is both .present? and .displayed? on the page) as well as the .present? and .displayed? methods themselves if you would like additional granularity in your testing. I will summarize below to make sure this all makes sense.

```
watir_element.exists?  #=> returns true if the element exists
watir_element.visible? #=> returns true if the element is visible on the page
watir_element.present? #=> returns true if the element exists & is visible on the page
```

I would definitely suggest bookmarking the [Watir Cheat Sheet](https://github.com/watir/watir/wiki/Cheat-Sheet) on GitHub while you are learning as it helps break down some of the more common problems you will run into as well as the [Watir Wiki](https://github.com/watir/watir/wiki) in general. Lastly, [Watir Webdriver.com](http://watirwebdriver.com/web-elements/) has a lot of solid resources as well.